# google-api-java-client: getContentLength coming as null in the HttpResponse

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

We are using google-api-java-client(old version). Since four days we are facing issue with the responses that we get from google. We have not done any changes, but we see that there was a newer version released exactly on the same date

http://google-http-java-client.blogspot.com/2014/04/version-1180-rc-released.html

The usage is as below. We establish connection to google using [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/ClientLogin). After that we create a `HttpRequest` object using the below API

```
request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
HttpResponse response = request.execute();
response.getHeaders().getContentLength(); // This line is now giving null
```

The last line where we use getContentLength() is giving `null`. Though we have not changed our version of google-api-java-client, we are facing this issue suddenly. Did anyone face such an issue or have any pointers of what could have gone wrong?